# Displaying state as css prop with state. Inline styling in reactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a progress bar from a bootstrap theme, that I want to use to display the progress, of signing up on a submission form.
I have made a state variable called progress, which I increment using different handlers, that configure the input.

For example my password handlers, that checks the password using a regex string.

```
passwordValidator = (password) =>{
var passwordRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([a-zA-Z0-9](_|-| )[a-zA-Z0-9])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/; // find bedre regex pattern
if (passwordRegex.test(password)) {
  this.setState({
    isPasswordCorrect: true,
    progress: this.state.progress +25
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    isPasswordCorrect: false
  });
}
console.log("password is " +this.state.isPasswordCorrect);
}
```

here I increment the progress count if the password is validated

```
<div class="progress">
 <div class="progress-bar" {/* other css props */} style= 
  {{width: ''}}></div>
 </div>
```

here I want to set the style property of the width to the state progress, but I need to include the percentage sign, so I was wondering if you could concatenate the `%` and make it into a string?

```
 <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" {/* other css props */} style= 
 {{width: this.state.progress +'%'}}></div>
 </div>
```

or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answer was to use a template string literal, so i could access the state using the dollar sign notation

```
style={{width: `${this.state.progress}%`}}
```